# $_POST values empty on server but works with localhost

Tags: php, vue.js, phpmailer

I have a VUE app posting to a PHP backend using PHPMailer for sending emails. In my local setup, the VUE frontend posts to PHP with no problem and emails are sending with content. Since migrating my code to a staging server, the frontend posts with no issue, emails are sending, but the emails are sending with no content. On form submission, `formData` is logging the correct values so it does look like the data is being sent, just something on the PHP side not working quiet right.

I'm a bit confused as to why this might be happening. If anyone is able to point out an issue or a better way to achieve what i'm trying to do it would be appreciated.

**Submit Method**

```
methods: {
    onSubmit() {
      this.sending =! this.sending;
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('winningUid', this.winningUid);
      formData.append('name', this.form.name);
      formData.append('email', this.form.email);
      formData.append('address1', this.form.address1);
      formData.append('address2', this.form.address2);
      formData.append('city', this.form.city);
      formData.append('county', this.form.county);
      formData.append('postCode', this.form.postCode);
      formData.append('mobileNumber', this.form.mobileNumber);
      formData.append('deliveryInstructions', this.form.deliveryInstructions);
      formData.append('sfu', this.form.sfu);
    
      axios.post('/api', formData).then(res => {
        console.log('SUCCESS', res.data);
        this.mailSent = true;
        this.data_captcher = false;

        for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
          console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
        }

      }).catch(err => {
        console.log('ERROR', err);
      });
    }
  }
```

**Mailing Script**

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

    // PHPMailer Object
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); 

    // Test using SendGrid
    $mail->isSMTP();  
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;            
    $mail->Port       = 587;                
    $mail->Host       = 'xxx';
    $mail->Username   = 'xxx'; 
    $mail->Password     = 'xxx';

  // Vars
    $uid = isset($_POST['winningUid']) ? $_POST['winningUid'] : ''; 
    $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : ''; 
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : ''; 
    $address1 = isset($_POST['address1']) ? $_POST['address1'] : ''; 
    $address2 = isset($_POST['address2']) ? $_POST['address2'] : ''; 
    $city = isset($_POST['city']) ? $_POST['city'] : ''; 
    $county = isset($_POST['county']) ? $_POST['county'] : ''; 
    $postCode = isset($_POST['postCode']) ? $_POST['postCode'] : ''; 
    $mobileNumber = isset($_POST['mobileNumber']) ? $_POST['mobileNumber'] : ''; 
    $deliveryInstructions = isset($_POST['deliveryInstructions']) ? $_POST['deliveryInstructions'] : ''; 

    //From email address and name
    $mail->From = 'send@email.com';
    $mail->FromName = $name;

    //To address and name
    $mail->addAddress("send@email.com", "To");

    //Address to which recipient will reply
    $mail->addReplyTo("reply@yourdomain.com", "Reply");

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Winning submission #' . $uid; 

    // Get required email template
    $email_template = 'templates/default.html';
    $template = file_get_contents($email_template);

    // Build content variables
    $template = str_replace('*|UID|*', $uid, $template);
    $template = str_replace('*|FULLNAME|*', $name, $template);
    $template = str_replace('*|EMAIL|*', $email, $template);
    $template = str_replace('*|ADDRESS1|*', $address1, $template);
    $template = str_replace('*|ADDRESS2|*', $address2, $template);
    $template = str_replace('*|CITY|*', $city, $template);
    $template = str_replace('*|COUNTY|*', $county, $template);
    $template = str_replace('*|POSTCODE|*', $postCode, $template);
    $template = str_replace('*|MOBILENUMBER|*', $mobileNumber, $template);
    $template = str_replace('*|DELIVERYINSTRUCTIONS|*', $deliveryInstructions, $template);

    $mail->MsgHTML($template);

    try {
        $mail->send();
        echo "Message has been sent successfully";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
```

Comment: First I whant to mention: Sanitize your data. If a variable needs to be an integer, make sure it will be an integer. Same for strings and escape unwanted characters. Also check if the posted email address is really an email address. Never trust the data from an users. Your script  depents on posted data, so also make sure the request was a post request you can easly do that with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'`

Comment: What if you do `var_dump($_POST)`, you get all the data? Is the path to your email template right? What you get if you var dump the template before replacing. For debugging things like this I highly recommend you to using xdebug

Comment: _"the emails are sending with no content"_... exactly what is and is not set as expected? Does the subject line contain the appropriate `$uid`? Is the `FromName` set correctly? If it's only the message body that is empty, I'd make sure that the `templates/default.html` was deployed correctly and that the path is where you think it is. In fact, I'd highly recommend using `$email_template = __DIR__ . "/templates/default.html";`

Comment: Looks to me like your "template" file is the culprit. Are you actually returning a string from that?

Comment: @Baracuda078 `$_POST` is just returning `array(0) {}`. For testing i've replaced the email template with `$mail->Body = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b> - ' .  $uid;` to see what is sent. The email is received with the HTML text, but the variable isn't displaying any data.

I will also be adding some guards to the script once i've got it working. Thank you for reminding me tho!

Comment: @Phil the email is sent and received, but there isn't any dynamic content in the email. Just certain hardcoded HTML content.  I will check the paths, but it all worked locally.

Comment: @Jamie_D the template is being picked up as the email received contains hardcoded HTML content which is in the template, just the dynamic content is missing.

Comment: @Baracuda078 additionally, `$_POST` is returning data locally, just staging server where the issue is present.

Comment: What if you try to just post the data with old school `XMLHttpRequest` I also had once verry strange behavior when I tried to post data with the fetch api while it was working just fine with jquery ajax post. My post data on the server whas also empty. It had something to do with the headers of the request and the way I sended the data within the function

Comment: @Baracuda078 so it looks as though the issue was down to my Axios.post. I had it written as `axios.post('/api', formData)`. Updating it to `axios.post('/api/index.php', formData)` has passed the data and emails are now sending with content!! In my vue.config I had a proxy setup to target ` 'http://localhost/index.php',` which is why it was working locally as I was hitting the actual file!!!